# change xml sample to xmldocument

Tags: c#, xml

I have a program that reads a tab delimited file and builds a sample xml file.

```
\t\t\troot
\t\t\t\tnode1
```

Output:

```
<root><node1></node1></root>
```

I would like to change the logic of the program to build a string representation of building an xmldocument **not xml** of c# building an xmldocument for automation purposes.

For instance(actual text of document)

```
"XmlElement XElemRoot = xDoc.CreateElement("root");

XmlElement XElemSecond = xDoc.CreateElement("node1");

XElemRoot.AppendChild(XElemSecond);"
```

Current code:

```
 string[] files = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\dell\test\xmlsamplemaker\xmlsampler\xmlsampler\bin\Debug\textofxml.txt");
 string newXml = string.Empty;string[] xmlHolder;
 List<int> levels = new List<int>();
        var lastlevel = 0;

        Stack<String> stack = new Stack<String>();

        for (int lines = 0; lines < files.Length; lines++)  //start
        {
            var firstNode = files[lines].TrimEnd('\t');
            levels.Add(TextTool.CountStringOccurrences(firstNode, "\t"));  //first count
            if (lines == 0)
            {
                newXml += "<" + files[lines].Replace("\t", "") + ">" + System.Environment.NewLine;
                stack.Push(files[lines].Replace("\t", ""));
            }
            else{
                if (levels[levels.Count - 1] == levels[levels.Count - 2])
                {
                    newXml += "</" + stack.Pop() + ">" + System.Environment.NewLine;
                    newXml += "<" + files[lines].Replace("\t", "") + ">" +System.Environment.NewLine;
                    stack.Push(files[lines].Replace("\t", ""));
                }
                else if (levels[levels.Count - 1] > levels[levels.Count - 2])
                {
                    newXml += "<" + files[lines].Replace("\t", "") + ">" + System.Environment.NewLine;
                    stack.Push(files[lines].Replace("\t", ""));
                }
                else
                {
                    newXml += "</" + stack.Pop() + ">" + System.Environment.NewLine;
                    newXml += "</" + stack.Pop() + ">" + System.Environment.NewLine;
                    newXml += "<" + files[lines].Replace("\t", "") + ">" + System.Environment.NewLine;
                    stack.Push(files[lines].Replace("\t", ""));
                }
            }
        }
        var size = stack.Count;
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        {
            newXml += "</" + stack.Pop() + ">" + System.Environment.NewLine;
        }

        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:\dell\xmlsample.xml", newXml);
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is a good starting point or if I should make something new.

Comment: Scrap this. Don't ever create XML by using string manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to use an `XmlWriter` - then:

```
newXml += "<" + files[lines].Replace("\t", "") + ">" + System.Environment.NewLine;
```

becomes

```
writer.WriteStartElement(files[lines].Replace("\t", "") );
```

and

```
newXml += "</" + stack.Pop() + ">" + System.Environment.NewLine;
```

becomes

```
writer.WriteEndElement();
```

etc. - where `writer` is the `XmlWriter` instance. Note that in this way you don't need to keep any more in the stack the name of the open elements - the writer does that for you (and you can use a simple counter to keep track of how many open element there are).

Once your code uses the `XmlWriter`, you can go directly to file, or to any stream, or to a string (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwriter.create.aspx)) or to an `XmlDocument` using [`XmlNodeWriter`](http://www.gotdotnet.com/Community/UserSamples/Details.aspx?SampleGuid=8F9DE8A7-FEC9-48E1-91C5-1FC569CDE11C).

**UPDATE**

To generate C# code that creates the `XmlDocument` the 'elegant' - but probably over-the-top = solution is to implement a custom `XmlWriter` that generates the code text. The source code of `XmlNodeWriter` would be a good starting point.

Otherwise just replace the string concatenations of the current code with similar string containing the C# code...

Comment: I don't think I explained myself well.  I have a /t/troot1 /t/t/tnode2 I want back a string like ""XmlElement XElemRoot = xDoc.CreateElement("root");
XmlElement XElemSecond = xDoc.CreateElement("node1");
XElemRoot.AppendChild(XElemSecond);"     I don't want it is xml I want it as I would write it in c# xmldocument.

Comment: Ah, I see - I did not get that. Expanding my answer.